# at least one object must implement icomparable. orderby descending C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to order the list of Custom object by its nested object property `updatedDate` but it throws error. I want to order the Store list based on nested property field `PartsInformation.updatedDate` then by `PartsDetail.updatedDate`. If you need more details, let me know and I will try to update it. I tried with `Icomparable` but I'm new to that so I didn't proceed further.

Class Structure:

```
public class StoreHomeInfo
{
    public string StoreID { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public List<OperationalUnit> OperationalUnitData { get; set; }
}

public class OperationalUnit
{      
    public string OunitID { get; set; }
    public string OunitName { get; set; }
    public List<PartsInformation> PartData { get; set; }
    public List<PartsDetail> PartCost { get; set; }
}

public class PartsInformation
{
    public string PartID { get; set; }
    public string Partname { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }       
    public string StoreID { get; set; }
    public string OunitID { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? updatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class PartsDetail
{
    public string PartsDetailID { get; set; }
    public string PartDetailName { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string OunitID { get; set; }
    public string StoreID { get; set; }      
    public DateTime? updatedDate { get; set; }       
}
```

Sample Query :

```
var result = (from st in lstobjStoreDetails
                group st by new { st.ID, st.Storename } into grouped
                    select new StoreHomeInfo()
                    {
                        StorID = grouped.Key.ID, 
                        StoreName = grouped.Key.Storename,
                        OperationalUnitData = (from ser in lstobjOpUnitDetails
                            where ser.StorID.Equals(grouped.Key.ID)
                            group ser by new { ser.ID, ser.Ounitname } into 
                            grouped1
                            select new OperationalUnit()
                            {
                                OunitID = grouped1.Key.ID,
                                OunitName = grouped1.Key.Ounitname,
                                PartsInformation = (from projes in lstobjpartDetails
                                      where projes.OunitID.Equals(grouped1.Key.ID)
                                      group serviceBS by new { projes.PartID, projes.Partname, projes.StorID, projes.OunitID,projes.updatedDate } into groupedparts
                                      select new PartsInformation()
                                      {
                                           PartID = lstobjpartDetails.Where(q => q.StorID == grouped.Key.ID && q.OunitID == grouped1.Key.ID && q.PartID ==  groupedparts.Key.PartID).FirstOrDefault() != null ? lstobjpartDetails.Where(q =>  q.StorID == grouped.Key.ID && q.OunitID == grouped1.Key._ID && q.PartID ==  groupedparts.Key.PartID).FirstOrDefault().PartID : null,
                                           Partname = groupedparts.Key.Partname,
                                           Summary = groupedparts.Key.Summary,
                                           OunitID = grouped1.Key.ID,
                                           StorID = grouped.Key.ID,
                                           updatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(groupedparts.Key.updatedDate)
                                      }).ToList(),
                                PartCost = (from pes in lstobjpartCostDetails
                                            where pes.OunitID.Equals(grouped1.Key._ID)
                                            group serviceBS by new { pes.PartsDetailID, pes.PartDetailName, pes.OunitID, pes.Summary pes.updatedDate, pes.StorID} into grouped2
                                            select new PartsDetail()
                                            {
                                                PartsDetailID = lstobjpartCostDetails.Where(q => q.StorID == grouped.Key._ID && q.OunitID == grouped1.Key._ID && q.PartsDetailID == grouped2.Key.PartsDetailID).FirstOrDefault() != null ? lstobjpartCostDetails.Where(q => q.StorID == grouped.Key._ID && q.OunitID == grouped1.Key._ID && q.PartsDetailID == grouped2.Key.PartsDetailID).FirstOrDefault().PartsDetailID : null,
                                                PartDetailName = grouped2.Key.PartDetailName,
                                                Summary = grouped2.Key.Summary,
                                                StorID = grouped.Key.ID,
                                                OunitID = grouped1.Key.ID,
                                                updatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(grouped2.Key.updatedDate)
                                            }).ToList()
                            }).ToList()
                    }).OrderByDescending(n => n.OperationalUnitData.OrderByDescending(p => p.PartCost != null && p.PartCost.Any() ? p.PartCost.OrderByDescending(q => q.updatedDate) : null)
                          .ThenBy(x => x.PartsInformation != null && x.PartsInformation.Any() ? x.PartsInformation.OrderByDescending(y => y.updatedDate) : null)).ToList();
```

Comment: *What* error is it throwing? Knowing that will go a long way towards diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @JuliaHayward  error message:  "at least one object must implement icomparable" theis the only content i'm getting in error message

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code:

`.OrderByDescending(p => p.PartCost != null && p.PartCost.Any() ? p.PartCost.OrderByDescending(q => q.updatedDate) : null)`

is trying to order a list of `OperationalUnit`s, but the key on which you're ordering by is a `List<PartCost>`. I suspect you want a *member* of that list to order by.

As an aside, you're trying to do a lot of work in one line and your code would be far clearer if you separated out methods to go into the `OrderByDescending` calls.

Comment: i'm not trying to order Operation Unit alone also the storeinfo its kind of cyclic ordering based on the PartsInformation and Part Cost updated Dates, goal is to give recent list of stores info based on its nested childs( parts Informations, Parts Cost), but  thanks for showing your interest